# Mutable vs. Immutable

Tags: stack, immutability, mutable

What should be considered to make a mutable class immutable? For example: Can we still have push and pop methods in an immutable stack class? Or we should simply remove any method that changes the state of the instantiated object?

Comment: If you can push a new element into the stack, it's not immutable.

Comment: Why would the `size` of `this` grow if you've only modified the `newElement` array?

Comment: You want to change the state of an _immutable_ object? How and why?

Comment: @AndyThomas not if it returns a new stack (not the case here of course).

Comment: I know that the state should not be changed but how can I get the size for the returned object from push and pop methods?

Comment: @AndyThomas No I am not pushing a new element into the stack. That's why the push method is not void. It just returns a deep copy of the stack including the new element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom line is: You'd be better to remove the method modifying the state of the instantiated object from the class. But if you want to keep it, then it should create a new object with a different state from the original one and return the new object back.

Here is a more specific answer:

There shouldn't be any methods changing the object state in an immutable class.

There are a lot of void methods which change the state of this object in a mutable class. So we should change the signature of them in a way the return a new object instead of changing "this" object's state.

Also there are a lot of non-void methods which change the state of "this" object and return the value they changed in "this". The signature of these methods should also be changed in a way that they return a new object instead of changing the state of "this". Talking about lists, usually another method (like "peek") is also needed to get a certain value. Check the sample bellow to get what do I mean:

Check out these "push" and "pop" methods for a mutable stack class:

```
public class Stack <E> {
…
public void push (E e) {
     ensureCapacity();  // This method checks for capacity
     elements[size++] = e;
   }
```

This method adds a new element at the top of the stack and changes the state of "this" object in this way.

```
public E pop () {
     if (size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack.pop");
     E result = elements[--size];
     elements[size] = null;
     return result;
   }
…
}
```

This method removes the element at the top of the stack and returns it back and changes the state of "this" object by removing the element.

Now, suppose that we need to change these methods to make this stack immutable. Let's deal with "push" method first:

"push" is a void method which changes the state of "this" object by adding a new element to it. To make the stack immutable we will create a new stack similar to "this" and add the new element to this new stack and return it back:

```
public class ImmStack <E> {
...
    /**
     * this method pushes the item to a new object and keeps the original object unchanged 
     * @param e The item to be pushed
     * @return A new list
     * @PRE An original list object is required as well as an item to be pushed
     * @POST A new list would be returned
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" }) // All items in this.elements[] are of type E
    public ImmStack<E> push (E e) {

         ImmStack<E> stc = new ImmStack(getNewElements());       
         stc.elements=ensureCapacity(stc.elements);
         stc.elements[size] = e;
         stc.size = size +1;         
         return stc;
       }
```

"pop" method changes the state of "this" object by removing an element. To make the class immutable we will reate a new stack similar to "this" and remove the element from this new stack and return it back:

```
   /**
     * This pop method returns a new stack without the element at the top of the original list 
     * @return The new stack
     * @POST The new stack would be returned
     */
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" }) // All items in this.elements[] are of type E
    public ImmStack<E> pop () {

        if (size == 0) throw new IllegalStateException("Stack.pop");

        ImmStack<E> stc = new ImmStack(getNewElements());        
         stc.elements=ensureCapacity(stc.elements);
         stc.elements[size-1] = null;
         stc.size=size-1;  
         return stc;
       }
```

The old "pop" method was returning the element at the top. We also need a new method which returns the element at the top to cover this feature:

```
   /**
    * Returns item at front of queue without removing.
    * @return item at front
    * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if empty
    */
   public E top()
   {
    if (this.isEmpty())
        {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Queue underflow");
        }
       return elements[size-1];
   }
```

This was just an example. You might have more methods to change in your class to make it immutable.

Answer (score 1):

If your stack is immutable, then by definition it cannot be changed. The `push()` and `pop()` methods cannot be completed.

When a method cannot be completed successfully, you can throw an exception. When a method can *never* be completed successfully, the standard exception to throw is `UnsupportedOperationException`.

For example:

```
public E[] push (E e) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
}
```

**EDIT:**

You note in a comment that your push() method is just returning a deep copy of the stack with the new element. It looks like you're representing the immutable stack as an instance of a class, and the pushed stack as an array.

You can get the size of one of the two arrays referenced by `newElements` with `newElements.length`. So you could write code like this:

```
public E[] push (E e) {
   E[] newElements=getNewElements();
   int oldLength = newElements.length;
   newElements=ensureCapacity(newElements);
   int lastIndexInNewArray = oldLength;
   newElements[ lastIndexInNewArray ] = e;
   return newElements;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an implementation of immutable stack in C#.

Pushing and popping give you back an entirely new stack, and Peek lets you look at the top of the stack without popping it.

Note that copying the entire stack is not necessary.

That is how immutable structures are implemented in any nontrivial cases. Nontrivial immutable structures are very useful in certain cases. Posters saying that this cannot be done are much misinformed.

The original code and more information can be found here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/12/04/immutability-in-c-part-two-a-simple-immutable-stack/

```
public interface IStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    IStack<T> Push(T value);
    IStack<T> Pop();
    T Peek();
    bool IsEmpty { get; }
}

public sealed class Stack<T> : IStack<T>
{
    private sealed class EmptyStack : IStack<T>
    {
        public bool IsEmpty { get { return true; } }
        public T Peek() { throw new Exception("Empty stack"); }
        public IStack<T> Push(T value) { return new Stack<T>(value, this); }
        public IStack<T> Pop() { throw new Exception("Empty stack"); }
        public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() { yield break; }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return this.GetEnumerator(); }
    }
    private static readonly EmptyStack empty = new EmptyStack();
    public static IStack<T> Empty { get { return empty; } }
    private readonly T head;
    private readonly IStack<T> tail;
    private Stack(T head, IStack<T> tail)
    {
        this.head = head;
        this.tail = tail;
    }
    public bool IsEmpty { get { return false; } }
    public T Peek() { return head; }
    public IStack<T> Pop() { return tail; }
    public IStack<T> Push(T value) { return new Stack<T>(value, this); }
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for(IStack<T> stack = this; !stack.IsEmpty ; stack = stack.Pop())
            yield return stack.Peek();
    }
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {return this.GetEnumerator();}
}
```